# Monorepo setup and issue

Tags: javascript, storybook, monorepo, lerna, yarn-workspaces

I have a monorepo project setup with subpackages i manage.

Within these packages, some may depend on one or another within the same monorepo packages.

So, for example:

— Packages

- componentB
- componentA (depends on component A)

Within the package.json of componentA, componentB is set as dependency but as “file://“

This is due the fact that if i change something in componentA and B, changes in B will be directly visible in A without publishing to the repository.

For development this works perfectly fine, but how does this work when i only want to use componentA in another webapp as dependency?

The other webapp does not need componentB as dependency, but only componentA.

How does componentA, which relies on componentB, installs componentB since it was declared as file dependency?

——

A solution would be to let componentA depend on componentB with a version number instead of a file reference.

The problem then will be that if i simultaneously working on A and B, changes on B wouldnt be directly visible in A unless i release the changes in B first.

——

Im using a monorepo setup with yarn and lerna.

Anyone familiar with this problem or are there any best practices for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `componentB is set as dependency but as “file://“` this is not needed for real. For example, you can use `npm link` or different setups for development and publishing. Anyway, your question seems more related to [Soft Eng](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: your alternate solution is probably the way to go, Lerna takes care of which package depends on which and also takes care of publishing them in topological order. Another thing that you could maybe use if the [`workspace:`](https://pnpm.io/workspaces#workspace-protocol-workspace) protocol (with pnpm or yarn 3) which would enforce local use (similar to file://), however Lerna does not currently support it (they have an open PR so it's coming soon), on the other hand [Lerna-Lite](https://github.com/ghiscoding/lerna-lite) does support since a few months already